# How to Update Control When Layers are Changed

Tags: openlayers

I have a control that allows the user to switch between satellite/street tiles. I want the text to update to show the next tile text when appropriate. Currently I am using the Control.render hook but this runs whenever the view changes. I just want a function to run when the control is added to a map and whenever the tile layers are modified. Is there an event I could listen to for that?

Here is the constructor of my current code:

```
constructor(options: any) {

    const button = document.createElement("button");
    const element = document.createElement("div");
    element.appendChild(button);

    super({
      ...options,
      element,
      target: options.target,
      render: () => {
        button.innerHTML = this.getNextLayer().getProperties().label;
      }
    });

    button.addEventListener("click", this.switchTileSet.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to update the label here is when you switch the layers. If I follow your code correctly you could do something like this,

```
constructor(options: any) {
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    // initialize label
    button.innerHTML = this.getNextLayer().getProperties().label;
    const element = document.createElement("div");
    element.appendChild(button);

    super({
      ...options,
      element,
      target: options.target
    });

    button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        this.switchTileSet.bind(this);
        // update label after switch
        button.innerHTML = this.getNextLayer().getProperties().label;
    });
}
```

Comment: That is what I initially did, but setting the initial label doesn't work because the control isn't attached to a map and there are no layers on the map yet (this.getNextLayer() requires this.getMap(), which does not work when the control is created). I need something that will fire when the control is bound to the map or layers are loaded.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you switching basemap layers in the control?.

Comment: Basemap meaning tile layers (OSM, Bing, etc) right?  Then yes.

Comment: Ok, so then I think that you should pass as a parameter the next layer label (or similar, next layer, first layer, etc..), and set the initial value with it. Then on button click switch and update the label.